# Create calculated value based on calculated value with the previous and next value

Tags: mysql, azure-databricks

I have the following table:

[ORIGINAL TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTzaG.png)

This table contains the quarterly score for each id, although not all quarters have this data.

I need to fill in the null values ​​of the intermediate months based on the value of the previous quarterly report and the value of the following quarter by applying the following formulas:

first month left=last score quarter*(1+(last score quarter/next score quarter) ^ (1/3)-1)

second month left=first month left*(1+(last score quarter/next score quarter) ^ (1/3)-1)

If the previous or next value is null then I must keep looking for the one that is not null and Same for missing quarters.

I try the following BUT is not enough:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW CALIFICACION_CALC AS 
SELECT 
  id,
        MONTH,
        QUARTER,
        year,
        SCORE_QUARTER,
  CASE
    WHEN LAST_VALUE IS NULL THEN (
      SELECT MIN(SCORE_QUARTER) 
      FROM TABLE
      WHERE (year < t.year OR (year = t.year AND QUARTER< t.QUARTER) OR (year = t.year AND QUARTER= t.QUARTER AND MONTH< t.MONTH))
        AND SCORE_QUARTER IS NOT NULL 
    )
    ELSE LAST_VALUE
  END AS LAST_VALUE,
  CASE
    WHEN NEXT_VALUE IS NULL THEN (
      SELECT MAX(SCORE_QUARTER) 
      FROM TABLE
      WHERE (year > t.year OR (year = t.year AND QUARTER> t.QUARTER) OR (year = t.year AND QUARTER= t.QUARTER AND MONTH> t.MONTH))
        AND SCORE_QUARTERIS NOT NULL
    )
    ELSE NEXT_VALUE
  END AS NEXT_VALUE
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ID,
    MONTH,
    QUARTER,
    year,
    SCORE_QUARTER,
    LAG(SCORE_QUARTER) OVER (PARTITION BY CLAVE_TIENDA,YEAR,QUARTER,MONTH ORDER BY year, QUARTER, MONTHASC) AS LAST_VALUE,
    LEAD(SCORE_QUARTER) OVER (PARTITION BY CLAVE_TIENDA,YEAR,QUARTER,MONTH ORDER BY year, QUARTER, MONTH) AS NEXT_VALUE
  FROM TABLE
) AS t ORDER BY year,QUARTER,MONTH;
```

THE DESIRED TABLE IS AS FOLLOWS:

[DESIRE TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1y0X.png)

Comment: MySQL or Azure? remove unrelated tag.